# MySQL: Update user record with value from next user record

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID    | uid   | vcode   | vcode_next
1       1       abc
2       2       def
3       2       ghi
4       1       jkl
5       1       mno
```

and I need to update vcode_next with the next vcode for a given user ID. So the result should be:

```
ID    | uid   | vcode   | vcode_next
1       1       abc       jkl
2       2       def       ghi
3       2       ghi       
4       1       jkl       mno
5       1       mno
```

I've seen some similar questions which have different demands selecting the update value, but I can't quite figure out how to implement this for the next value for a given user-id.

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `JOIN` with the same table and perform the `UPDATE` like

```
UPDATE table1 a 
    JOIN table1 b ON a.uid = b.uid AND a.ID < b.ID
SET a.vcode_next = b.vcode;
```

**EDIT:**

The posted query works fine and gives exact rsult per your post. See this demo fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f020/1 for a proof. It results in below after `UPDATE`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this doesn't seem to take into account the fact that I need to update the previous uid entry with the value from the next uid entry. I'm not sure what exactly this does, but it certainly doesn't produce the desired result.

Comment: I haven't tested it but logically it should work as expected. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to observe the order required by ID and UID.

Comment: I really doubt you tried. check edited answer and the posted fiddle link. answered query gives exact result per your post.

Comment: I tested it but my query to verify the results was incorrect. I stand corrected, it works. Thank you very much!